# Postgresql query json element inside json array

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE stats
(
  item character varying,
  data jsonb
);

it contains values like 
ITEM        DATA
test1       [{"id":"1", "country":"UK"},{"id":"2", "country":"INDIA"}] 
test2       [{"id":"1", "country":"US"},{"id":"4", "country":"CHINA"},{"id":"5", "country":"CHINA"}]
```

I need to get number of distinct json objects where country is 'CHINA' and item is '%test%';
In this case the output should be 2, ie, [{"id":"4", "country":"CHINA"},{"id":"5", "country":"CHINA"}]

I am using the following query

```
SELECT  * FROM   stats t
WHERE ( data @> '[{"country":"CHINA"}]')
and t.item ilike '%test%';

output : [{"id":"1", "country":"US"},{"id":"4", "country":"CHINA"},{"id":"5", "country":"CHINA"}]
```

What should i do so that i get the array of objects which has 'CHINA' as countries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements()` to get single json objects, filter them and use `jsonb_agg()` to aggregate into a json array.

```
select item, jsonb_agg(obj)
from stats, jsonb_array_elements(data) obj
where obj->>'country' = 'CHINA'
group by 1;
```

Comment: ERROR: function jsonb_agg(jsonb) does not exist
SQL state: 42883

Comment: [`jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) is available in the current (9.5) Postgres version. In Postgres 9.4 you can try [`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html).